# Label group of plots

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, facet, patchwork

I merged nine plots together and I would like to group them based on different characteristics (A,B,C). Is there a simple way to add labels or annotations at the bottom of plots? When using `cowplot` or `GridExtra` i receive the following error:

```
 In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.
```

Sample data

```
list(list(stats = structure(c(43, 96.5, 297.5, 707.5, 778), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                     1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(136.603333333333, 458.396666666667
                                                                     ), .Dim = 2:1), out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
     list(stats = structure(c(2, 10.5, 55.5, 102, 128), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                 1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(31.405, 79.595), .Dim = 2:1), 
          out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
     list(stats = structure(c(1, 3, 5.5, 77, 88), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                           1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(-13.9866666666667, 24.9866666666667
                                                           ), .Dim = 2:1), out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
     list(stats = structure(c(531, 632.5, 701, 726.5, 786), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                     1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(676.246666666667, 725.753333333333
                                                                     ), .Dim = 2:1), out = c(485, 464, 446), group = c(1, 1, 1
                                                                     ), names = ""), list(stats = structure(c(104, 
                                                                                                                                    109.5, 113.5, 121, 125), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(110.471666666667, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           116.528333333333), .Dim = 2:1), out = c(91, 91, 88, 84, 84, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   79), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), names = ""), 
     list(stats = structure(c(28, 53.5, 83.5, 88, 91), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(74.415, 92.585), .Dim = 2:1), 
          out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
     list(stats = structure(c(80, 89, 102.5, 153, 236), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                 1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(85.6466666666667, 119.353333333333
                                                                 ), .Dim = 2:1), out = c(343, 318, 299, 257), group = c(1, 
                                                                                                                        1, 1, 1), names = """"), list(stats = structure(c(7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            12, 22.5, 44, 72), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(14.0733333333333, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             30.9266666666667), .Dim = 2:1), out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), 
                                                                                                                                                                        names = ""), list(stats = structure(c(5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        5, 6, 12.5, 21), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), n = 36, conf = structure(c(4.025, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       7.975), .Dim = 2:1), out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    names = ""))
```

Many thanks
[image]

Comment: have a look at the `patchwork` package, but using facets, at least within each group, is probably a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the idea of using `ggplot2` graphics with facets, but given your plot objects, you could do something like this (to get you started). I used `ggplotify` instead of `cowplot` because I ran into trouble with the figure margins, but you might be able to fix that by changing the null device (not tested).

**Edit:**

Added individual labels and y axis labels, as well as outer margins. You might have to adjust some of that depending on the output size of your composite plot. This may show you how you could adjust those settings for individual plots. Still, using `ggplot2` to generate the plots would make things quite a bit easier.

```r
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplotify)
sdt <- list(list(stats = structure(c(43, 96.5, 297.5, 707.5, 778), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(136.603333333333, 458.396666666667), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(2, 10.5, 55.5, 102, 128), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(31.405, 79.595), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(1, 3, 5.5, 77, 88), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(-13.9866666666667, 24.9866666666667), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(531, 632.5, 701, 726.5, 786), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(676.246666666667, 725.753333333333), .Dim = 2:1),
                 out = c(485, 464, 446), group = c(1, 1, 1), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(104, 109.5, 113.5, 121, 125), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(110.471666666667, 116.528333333333), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = c(91, 91, 88, 84, 84, 79), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(28, 53.5, 83.5, 88, 91), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(74.415, 92.585), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(80, 89, 102.5, 153, 236), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(85.6466666666667, 119.353333333333), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = c(343, 318, 299, 257), group = c(1,1, 1, 1), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(7, 12, 22.5, 44, 72), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)), 
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(14.0733333333333, 30.9266666666667), .Dim = 2:1),
                 out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""), 
            list(stats = structure(c(5, 5, 6, 12.5, 21), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)),
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(4.025, 7.975), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = ""))
sublabels <- paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=3), 1:3)
gplts <- lapply(1:9, function(x) as.grob(function(y=sdt[[x]]) {
  par(oma=c(0,3,0,3))
  bxp(y, ylab="values", main=sublabels[x])}))
grid.arrange(rectGrob(gp=gpar(col="red")), rectGrob(gp=gpar(col="green")), 
             rectGrob(gp=gpar(col="yellow")), nrow=1, newpage =T)
vp <- viewport(.33/2,0.45, gp = gpar(col="red"))
grid.text("Group A",
          y = .1, just = c("center", "bottom"),
          gp = gpar(fontsize=20), vp = vp)
vp <- viewport(.5,.45, gp = gpar(col="green"))
grid.text("Group B",
          y = .1, just = c("center", "bottom"),
          gp = gpar(fontsize=20), vp = vp)

vp <- viewport(1-(.33/2),.45, gp = gpar(col="yellow"))
grid.text("Group C",
          y = .1, just = c("center", "bottom"),
          gp = gpar(fontsize=20), vp = vp)
grid.arrange(grobs=gplts, nrow=1, newpage=F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: many thanks, it looks great and I do understand the code, but how you name the y-axis of the plots. Also, I tried to name individually the plots (eg. A1, A2,A3,B1..) but the title is not recognized. Basically I tried something like this list(stats = structure(c(5, 5, 6, 12.5, 21), .Dim = c(5L, 1L)),
                 n = 36, conf = structure(c(4.025, 7.975), .Dim = 2:1), 
                 out = numeric(0), group = numeric(0), names = "A1"

Comment: see my edited answer for a possible solution